# How can I maintain polymorphism when creating an instance on stack in C++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

To create instance on the heap and maintain polymorphism, and that'll give the right answer:

```
class Father
{
    public:

        virtual void Say()
        {
            cout << "Father say hello" << endl;
        }
};


class Son : public Father
{
    public:
        void Say()
        {
            cout << "Son say hello" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Father*> v;
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;

    for(int i(0); i<5; i++)
    {
        auto p = new Son();    ---------------on heap
        v.emplace_back(p);
    }
    for(auto p : v)
    {
        p->Say();
    }
}
```

But when I want to create an instance on the stack, it seems not so easy:

Edition 1:

```
class Father
{
    public:

        virtual void Say()
        {
            cout << "Father say hello" << endl;
        }
};


class Son : public Father
{
    public:
        void Say()
        {
            cout << "Son say hello" << endl;
        }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Father> v;
    for(int i(0); i<5; i++)
    {
        auto o = Son();    ---------------on stack
        v.emplace_back(o);---------------now "o" is cast to Father type
    }

    for(auto o : v)
    {
        o.Say();------------------------only output "Father say hello"
    }
}
```

And edition 2:

```
class Father
{
    public:

        virtual void Say()
        {
            cout << "Father say hello" << endl;
        }
    };


class Son : public Father
{
    public:
        void Say()
        {
            cout << "Son say hello" << endl;
        }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Father*> v;
    for(int i(0); i<5; i++)
    {
        auto p = &Son();    --------------On the stack
        v.emplace_back(p);---------------Now "o" is cast to Father type
    }

    for(auto p : v)
    {
        p->Say();------------------------Since "p" now is a Wild pointer, it'll fail too
    }
}
```

Can this be fixed? Or is it just a dead end: If I want to use polymorphism, then I have to create an object on the heap.

Comment: For any automatic storage you need to know the number of objects you're creating beforehand - or use variable length arrays, but those are taboo around here. If you know you'll have 5 `Son`s, you can make a `Son[5]` array, then assign those addresses to 5 `Father` pointers. But note that your `std::vector<Father*> v` is holding the pointers in dynamically allocated memory, so if you want to avoid that entirely you'll need to use a local array instead.

Comment: `auto p= &Son();` is invalid because taking address of temporary is not allowed, at the same time saving pointers to variables that go out of scope is a failure as well. If you are strong pointers somewhere then you must ensure that objects they are pointing to survive for long enough,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recurring problem/dilemma: you can maintain a value semantic at the expense of some boilerplate code. Here is a minimal working example of such kind of idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Father
{
 protected:
  struct Father_Interface
  {
    virtual void
    Say() const
    {
      std::cout << "Father say hello" << std::endl;
    }
  };

  using pimpl_type = std::shared_ptr<const Father_Interface>;
  pimpl_type _pimpl;

  Father(const Father_Interface* p) : _pimpl(p) {}

 public:
  Father() : Father{new Father_Interface{}} {}

  void Say() const { _pimpl->Say(); }
};

class Son : public Father
{
 protected:
  class Son_Interface : public Father_Interface
  {
    void
    Say() const override
    {
      std::cout << "Son say hello" << std::endl;
    }
  };

 public:
  Son() : Father{new Son_Interface{}} {}

  Son& operator=(const Father&) = delete; // fight against object slicing
};

int
main()
{
  std::vector<Father> v;

  v.emplace_back(Father());
  v.emplace_back(Son());
  v.emplace_back(Father());

  for (const auto& v_i : v)
  {
    v_i.Say();
  }
}
```

which prints:

> ```
> Father say hello
> Son say hello
> Father say hello
> ```

You can also read about:

- [Sean Parent's better-code-runtime-polymorphism](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/papers-and-presentations/#better-code-runtime-polymorphism)
- [discussion about its usage](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/cikmhh/implemented_sean_parents_polymorphic_value_types/)

Comment: @scirocc Well... polymorphism with virtual methods and value semantic are a bit orthogonal. Be sure that you cannot design your code another way. Thank you and good luck

Answer (score 2):

In general polymorphism does not require dynamic allocations. That's a common misunderstanding, and hence here comes a counter example:

```
void foo(const Father& f) { f.Say(); }

Son s;
foo(s);
```

You have to declare `Say` as `const` to make it work, but then it will print the expected `Son say hello`. You need references or pointers for polymorphism, not necessarily dynamic allocation!

Having said this, when you want a container of derived classes, then `std::vector<Father>` won't do. Public inheritance models a "is-a" relation, so a `Son` is a `Father`, but a `Father` is not a `Son` (notice how wrong and misleading the father-son analogy is?!?). Hence when you put a `Son` into a vector of `Father`s, then the object gets sliced and only the `Father` part is stored in the vector (read about "object slicing").

Moreover, `auto p= &Son();` is wrong, because the created object is temporary and its life time ends at the end of that line. The pointer you store in the vector is dangling (it points to an object whose lifetime already ended).

To store pointers in the container you can use dynamic allocations. For example, with `std::unique_ptr`s:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Father>> v;
    for(int i(0);i<5;i++){
        v.emplace_back(new Son);
    }
    for(auto& p:v){
        p->Say();
    }

}
```

Note that you have to use `auto&` for the range based for loop, because `unique_ptr` doesn't copy. `unique_ptr` does the dirty work: the objects will get deleted automatically when the `unique_ptr`s get destroyed (which is when the vector goes out of scope).

Comment: thanks man,AFAIK,"make_unique" and "new" will create instance on heap. but how to create on stack?

Comment: @scirocc a `std::vector` always stores its element in dynamically allocated memory, no way around that. Using a pointer just adds a level of indirection. You can use `std::array` if you want it on the stack, but then you need to know the number of elements in advance

Comment: @scirocc you can store pointers to stack allocated objects in a vector (thats the other answer), but I dont understand why you want that

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things you are doing wrong. First here is how you can do it right:

```
int main()
{
    Father father1;
    Son son1;
    Father father2;
    Son son2;

    std::vector<Father*> v;
    v.emplace_back(&father1);
    v.emplace_back(&son1);
    v.emplace_back(&father2);
    v.emplace_back(&son2);

    for (auto p : v) {
        p->Say();
    }
}
```

Basically you need to allocate the objects on the stack so that the objects will be available for as long as the vector is.

Now what you did is undefined behavior, because you basically had pointers (in the vector) to objects that were already de-allocated (even if you fix what was already said in the comments).

```
    for(int i(0);i<5;i++){
        Son s;
        v.emplace_back(&s);
    // s lifetime end here, but the vector still has pointers to objects that are de-allocated
    }
```

For this bit: `v.emplace_back(p);---------------now "o" is cast to Father type`.

I think you tried something completely different: a vector of Father objects `std::vector<Father>` and if you try to add Son elements into that you get *object slicing* // I just added this bit so that you can look it up, this is not the main point here

Comment: thanks man,I know pre-declare will help,but if i wanna create thousands of objects on stack,how to do...

Comment: @scirocc You can create thousands of objects on the stack. Just declare thousands of variables and you are done.

Comment: Well you can't dynamically allocate memory on the stack, that is what dynamic memory allocation is used for. Also the stack is usually pretty small, so allocating thousands of objects on stack is not a good idea (because you can run out of stack memory).

Comment: Storing references or pointers to stack objects in a vector is not always a good idea, as of course, these objects must outlive the vector or else you get dangling pointers in the vector. Of course, it has its uses, but you really need to know what you're doing, of course - the vector itself will dynamically allocate room for the pointers, unless you use a custom allocator.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb yes, i agree with you, and basically that is what i was explaining that he needs to make sure that the objects live for as long as the vector of pointers is.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't have much to do with stack. You're really asking how to implement polymorphism when storing by value. It's not too hard if you can use C++17 and thus have `std::variant` available.

The implementation is surprisingly simple:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

enum class Who { Father, Son };

struct ISayer {
    virtual Who Me() const = 0;
    virtual ~ISayer() {};
};

struct Father final : ISayer {
    Who Me() const override { return Who::Father; }
};

struct Son final : ISayer {
    Who Me() const override { return Who::Son; }
};

struct AnySayer0 : std::variant<Father, Son>
{
    using variant_type = std::variant<Father, Son>;
    using variant_type::variant;
    operator const ISayer &() const {
        return std::visit([](auto &val) -> const ISayer &{ return val; },
        static_cast<const variant_type &>(*this));
    }
    operator ISayer &() {
        return std::visit([](auto &val) -> ISayer &{ return val; },
        static_cast<variant_type &>(*this));
    }
    const ISayer *operator->() const { return &static_cast<const ISayer &>(*this); }
    ISayer *operator->() { return &static_cast<ISayer &>(*this); }
};

using AnySayer = AnySayer0;

int main()
{
    std::vector<AnySayer> people;

    people.emplace_back(std::in_place_type<Father>);
    people.emplace_back(std::in_place_type<Son>);

    assert(people.front()->Me() == Who::Father);
    assert(people.back()->Me() == Who::Son);
}
```

An alternate implementation `AnySayer1` would need a bit more boilerplate, and perhaps be a bit faster - but would it be a bit smaller as well?

```
struct AnySayer1
{
    template <typename ...Args>
    AnySayer1(std::in_place_type_t<Father>, Args &&...args) :
        father(std::forward<Args>(args)...), ref(father) {}
    template <typename ...Args>
    AnySayer1(std::in_place_type_t<Son>, Args &&...args) :
        son(std::forward<Args>(args)...), ref(son) {}
    ~AnySayer1() { ref.~ISayer(); }
    operator const ISayer &() const { return ref; }
    operator ISayer &() { return ref; }
    const ISayer *operator->() const { return &static_cast<const ISayer &>(*this); }
    ISayer *operator->() { return &static_cast<ISayer &>(*this); }
    AnySayer1(AnySayer1 &&o) : ref(getMatchingRef(o)) {
        if (dynamic_cast<Father*>(&o.ref))
            new (&father) Father(std::move(o.father));
        else if (dynamic_cast<Son*>(&o.ref))
            new (&son) Son(std::move(o.son));
    }
    AnySayer1(const AnySayer1 &o) : ref(getMatchingRef(o)) {
        if (dynamic_cast<Father*>(&o.ref))
            new (&father) Father(o.father);
        else if (dynamic_cast<Son*>(&o.ref))
            new (&son) Son(o.son);
    }
    AnySayer1 &operator=(const AnySayer1 &) = delete;
private:
    union { 
        Father father;
        Son son;
    };
    ISayer &ref;
    ISayer &getMatchingRef(const AnySayer1 &o) {
        if (dynamic_cast<const Father *>(&o.ref))
            return father;
        if (dynamic_cast<const Son *>(&o.ref))
            return son;
        assert(false);
    }
};
```

This could be rewritten using the same "magic" that makes `std::variant` work - it'd be less repetitive that way.

But - is it smaller?

```
static_assert(sizeof(AnySayer1) == sizeof(AnySayer0));
```

No. At least in both gcc and clang, both implementations have the same size. And that makes sense, since `std::variant` doesn't need to store any more information than we do - it only needs to keep some way to discriminate the type. We chose to use the reference to `ISayer` and use dynamic type information, since that optimizes for the common case when we convert to the interface type - we store the reference ready to use. `std::variant` can't assume that the types have a common base, and instead stores an integer type index instead and uses generated code to dispatch on that index. It may be generally a bit slower in the path that uses the visitor to return the reference - but not necessarily, since the compiler can note that both types have their `ISayer` vtable pointer at the same location, and can squash the type-based dispatch down to a "has value vs has no value" test. It seems that the most recent versions of all major C++ compilers (gcc, clang and MSVC) easily deal with this and generate code that is just as fast as our "optimized" `AnySayer1`.